# Could not find migration class for migration step symfony doctrine

Tags: doctrine, symfony1

I am trying to migrate back to a previous step, I have accidentally deleted my current migration step '56'. When I run

```
php symfony doctrine:migrate 51
```

As expected, it throws an error "`Could not find migration class for migration step: 56`" -- this is due to me deleting the migration 56 class

What is the solution to roll back to the previous step "51", without having the current class already there

I am using an older version of symfony v 1.2

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by accessing the localhost/phpmyadmin and locating the table called 'migration version'

I ran a quick update query, and change the value to '51'

As follows

```
UPDATE `migration_version` SET `version`=51 WHERE 1
```

I hope this helps people in the future